# What's the proper way to use another project in your own open source software?

Tags: law, attribution

I am working on adding an entirely new set of features to an open source project that my team has created.
Before I got started though, I did some research to see what other were offering in that area etc.

Another open source project is already light-years ahead of us in this regard, and we would probably never catch up if we tried to do it ourselves from the ground up.

What would be the proper way to go about using their work in our own project?
I think some important topics to address would be:

- Attribution
- License Compatibility
- Implementation
- Restrictions on the Final Product

Comment: A nice question, but unfortunately far too broad - and I'm voting to close as such. You should narrow this down so the scope isn't so massive: we should be able to reasonably answer in a few short paragraphs. This, as it stands, would require a lot more.

Comment: Great thanks! I will break this up into more pointed questions and post them over the coming weeks.

Answer (score 1):

It is not unusual in the world of free software to reuse libraries pulled from other projects (adapted, or unchanged).

IMHO, there are really just two things you really need to be concerned about when doing this:

1. License Compatibility
2. Attribution

Speaking from experience, I would say that **license compatibility** may be a major obstacle when reusing code from another FLOSS project.

For instance, if your project is going to be made available under the GNU GPL version 2 (GPLv2), and the "other" project's library is available under Apache 2.0, you can't legally combine them, because Apache 2.0 is [*not* compatible with GPLv2](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.en.html#apache2). (Apache 2.0 is compatible with GPLv3 - but that is no comfort if *your* project's license is GPLv2). Note that dual licensing will not solve this, because dual licensing allow downstream recipients to *choose* a license, and you can't legally take Apache 2.0 and just permit relicensing to GPLv2.

I am been in this situation a number of times, and unless you have the privilege of re-licensing your own project (usually not feasible with a project that already have users relying on it keeping its license), the only route is to negotiate a with the owner of the *other* project that they allow the re-licensing.  My experience is that most owners are nice people and will be happy to do this.  But abandonware is a problem. There is a lot of abandoned code out there with weird custom licenses that is unusable in new projects because their owners are unreachable.

**Attribution** is required by law, and usually also by the FLOSS license. This is much simpler do deal with.  Just make sure you *do it*, and do it correctly.  My experience with some really large projects is that developers unfortunately are ignorant about this aspect of free software, and therefor sloppy in its execution.  In one of the FLOSS projects I manage, we're developing tools to assist our contributors in doing correct attribution.